# For what $k$ does $\sin(x)$ hit $kx$ 9 times

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I saw this problem online and I am pretty stuck with it, here is the problem

> For what $k$ does $kx$ intersect $\sin(x)$ exactly 9 times?

My first thought when looking at this problem was to divide out the $x$. I would then be left with $\sin(x)/x=k$
I then tried to find some clever limit or derivative to get the answer, but I am stuck. I assume there is some clever calculus I can do to get this answer, but I can't find it.

Thanks!

Comment: does k=0.075 works?

Comment: Maybe, I would like to see how you got that thought. Besides just guessing and checking

Comment: I ll try to writte a more complete and details answer. But i wrotte the series of the function $f(x)=sin(x)-kx$ until degree $9$ and after applied Sturm theorem to find a condition on k. The last part is a little bit long so i "tried to guess it"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is obvious that $0$ is a Point of Intersection.
Then Every Positive Point of Intersection will have a Matching Negative Point of Intersection.
Hence we want 4 Positive Points of Intersection.

This Image shows that line with Positive $k$.

[image: 4+1+4]

The line must be a tangent somewhere near the third Positive Peak.

The line is a tangent to the $y=\sin{x}$ curve , which has Derivative $dy/dx=\cos{x}=k$.
The line Passes through $(0,0)$ , hence the slope is $y/x=k$.
Hence , we get $dy/dx=\cos{x}=k=y/x=\sin{x}/x$.
Equivalently : $\tan{x}=x$

[image: X-TAN(X)]

Solving that , the Values are :
X = 0
X ≈ 4.49341
X ≈ 7.72525
X ≈ 10.9041
X ≈ 14.0662

The third Peak neighbourhood criteria gives X ≈ 14.0662.
Here $k=\cos{x}=0.070907387605$

[image: SIN(X)=X]

The values of $x$ & $k$ (& $\sin{x}$ & $\cos{x}$) work here !

Moving on :

When we look at Negative values of $k$, The Situation is entirely Different.

The Purple line has 3 Positive Points of Intersection, the Grey line has 5 Positive Points of Intersection.

[image: 3+4+5]

Between these two Extremities , we have the Black line with Exactly 4 Positive Points of Intersection.
Each Black line uses Negative value of $k$.

To get the range , we must evaluate the Extremities , that is , we check the tangent line near the second & the fourth Negative Peaks.

Comment: That's *one* line. There is also a range of lines with negative slopes!

Comment: Thanks for the Pointer , I have updated the Answer !! @HagenvonEitzen

Comment: This answer still doesn't answer what K is and how you could prove it. It just says look at some pictures and find it out for yourself

Comment: You said "I am pretty stuck with it" & then you said "I assume there is some clever calculus I can do to get this answer" : This Answer may not be clever , but it should help you get unstuck. It should also help you write the necessary Equations to make Progress. @SamuelMorrison

Comment: Saying $kx$ is tangent "somewhere" near the 3rd peak isn't helping me

Comment: Ok , I have elaborated more , Hope you can check it ! @SamuelMorrison

Comment: @SamuelMorrison There's some clever calculus in this answer but we also find out that clever calculus will only get you part way to the answer. Some numerical method also is required, for example to solve $\tan x = x.$

Comment: @prem Your answer is excellent now! I can see you put a lot of work into helping me! Thank You!